# How to complete a while loop in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if you could help me to complete this macro I am designing for an excel worksheet. I am trying to create a macro that selects and then cycles the colours of selected cells while a checkbox is ticked.I have included the current code below but I have tried this with a variety of loops including While...Wend. I may have completed these wrong though so it is possible that those options would still work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub Disco_Mode()
    '
    ' Disco_Mode Macro
    ' Activates disco mode for this worksheet.
    '
      
    '
    Range( _
        "31:1048576,J29:XFD30,U26:XFD28,J26:K28,A26:C30,22:25,O15:XFD21,A15:C21,12:14,W3:XFD11,A3:C11,1:2" _
        ).Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    Dim isOn As Boolean
    isOn = 1
    Dim volor As Integer
    volor = 0
    Do Until False
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = volor
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
    End If
    End Function
    End With
        
    Range("A1").Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you actually tried reading the MS help pages for if then else endif, with, end with, for do loops etc

Comment: Yes I have, I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I suggest you read again. You can't have an end if if there is no matching if. Similar observations for do until and end function. You also can't overlap blocks. E.g with ... If...end if... End with, not with ... If...end with...end if.

Comment: I am still struggling to get it to work.

Comment: Well booleans have two values 'True' and 'False'.  VBA can do truthy conversions if it must but its better to use the correct values.  Try a sub with only your first range statement, do you get an error? what happens when have your first two range statements only in the sub.  Is the first range still selected?  Lots more to comment on, but this just shows how very little research you have done.

Comment: The main problem is that I don't understand what you are saying. That is the reason I am asking for help. I have tried to research but would like for more specific help and as such have posted this question on a forum.

Comment: A good start would be to work your way through a VBA tutorial.  This is a forum for experienced amateurs or professional programmers who have hit an unexpected or poorly documented issue. your code above shows you don't understand the very basic faults in your code so helping you here isn't really helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Regularly, `while` loops work as follows:

```
while condition do:
  ...
  if ... then condition=false;
wend
```

Or (for a `do ... until` loop):

```
Do until condition:
...
if ... then condition=true;
```

Another way is:

```
while (true)
  ...
  if ... then break;
wend
```

This, however, does not work in Excel VBA (it's more a C/C++ way of working: the `break` causes an exit from the loop).

Therefore I would disadvise you to use a `Do ... Until False` and to replace it by a `Do ... Until condition` where the condition is set in the loop.